# php check if user input is not space

Tags: php, validation, input

I have the following code to check user input:

```
if(isset($_POST['block_name']) && !empty($_POST['block_name'])) {
    $block->name = trim($_POST['block_name']);
}
```

But it accepts SPACE as valid input, so I changed to this:

```
if(isset($_POST['block_name']) && !empty($_POST['block_name']) && trim($_POST['block_name'])!='') {
        $block->name = trim($_POST['block_name']);
    }
```

I have found on web that I can use !=false as well. What is the difference and which is recommended.

Comment: Please read the documentation on `empty` first. Your question regarding `false` is also answered in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`''` equals `false` in a loose comparison, so there's no real difference. Since `'0'` also equals `false` though, you may want to make your check more strict. `empty` is also just checking for `false` without triggering an error if the variable is not set. So `isset && !empty` is redundant to begin with.

Use:

```
if (isset($_POST['block_name']) && strlen(trim($_POST['block_name'])) > 0)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn`t know trim($_POST['name']) do not accept 0. So now I am using if(isset($_POST['block_name']) && trim($_POST['block_name'])!='') so that 0 can also be accepted as a single character. Is there anything not so good in my code now?

Answer (score 0):

you can check for the blank space with

```
  if( (strlen($string) == 1 ) && strpos(trim($string)," ")){

   echo "the string contains only a blank space";

  }
```

Comment: What is this supposed to achieve?

Comment: @Jon wants the OP to check if the string has only a blank space inside?

Answer (score 0):

`if(empty($_POST['block_name']))` should check:

```
"" (an empty string)
0 (0 as an integer)
0.0 (0 as a float)
"0" (0 as a string)
NULL
FALSE
array() (an empty array)
$var; (a variable declared, but without a value)
```

So, this should be best to go with: `if(!empty(trim($_POST['block_name']))) { //proceed...`

Comment: I don't think empty works with expressions :) The manual says that only 5.5 supports them

Comment: Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context

Comment: @jCloud .. it's good to assign `$blockName = $_POST['block_name']` in a variable and then try `empty` actually `if(!empty($blockName))`.

Comment: what will happen if $_POST['block_name'] is not set

Comment: if it's not set, `if` condition will not satisfy.

Comment: if it is not set, php gives this error: Notice: Undefined index: block_name on line where I do this $blockName = $_POST['block_name']

Answer (score 0):

Use this conditional statement. I hope it will work.

```
if `$custSTR` is a sample string having spaces.

$custSTR = '     ';
if (strlen(trim(preg_replace('/\xc2\xa0/',' ',$custSTR))) == 0)
{
    echo "custSTR have space or empty.\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After all I think this way is the best:

```
if(isset($_POST['block_name']) && strlen(trim($_POST['block_name'])) > 1) {
        $block->name = trim($_POST['block_name']);
    }
    else {
        $errors[] = "Please give a name for the new block. It should be at least 2 characters";
    }
```

Thanks for deceze for his answer.